# Drupal - Display form alter content

Tags: php, drupal

I have created a module with a hook_form_alter that adds an extra field called 'Phone', this gives the site administrator the ability to modify a site phone number.

Is there a way I can access this field data **without** an SQL query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean without an SQL statement being executed at all then no, you need to store the data somewhere you can retrieve it later. I suppose you could use a flat file if you're desperate but since Drupal relies on the database (so it'll always be there) I don't see any value to this.

If you're only bothered about not having to write SQL *yourself* then you can use the variable system, for which Drupal will handle the database calls.

```
// Set a variable
variable_set('site_phone_number', $the_number);

// Retrieve the variable
variable_get('site_phone_number', $default_if_variable_doesnt_exist);
```

[`variable_get() docs`](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=f&rct=j&url=http://api.drupal.org/variable_get&q=drupal+variable_get&usg=AFQjCNHYt1L9AUwvb4ANA92fe5vLVgZgMQ)
[`variable_set() docs`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7)